# apache mod_rewrite not working for root?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect ALL traffic for `http://*.domain.com` to `https://secure.domain.com`.

What I have so far:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias *.domain.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://secure.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

This seems to work for:

```
www.domain.com
www.domain.com/whatever
anything.domain.com
anything.domain.com/whatever
```

But not for:

```
domain.com
domain.com/whatever
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... disregard, I think:

Seems to be affecting only Chrome right now, and only in non-incognito mode.(?!)

Works as expected in Safari, Chrome (incognito) and Firefox (all on Mac).

Not working in Chrome (non-incognito mode)... perhaps some odd caching issue?